# Как обьект преобразовать в массив

Tags: javascript

Есть обьект objectUser

```
{name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов'}
```

как его преобразовать в массив

```
[name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов']
```

Comment: именно так - никак. либо просто запихи объект в массив )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `[name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов']`

Никак. В [js](/questions/tagged/js) нормальные массивы и нормальные объекты, а такой фигни нет.

Answer (score 4):

> Object.entries() метод возвращает массив собственных перечисляемых
> свойств указанного объекта в формате [key, value]

> Метод flat() возвращает новый массив, в котором все элементы вложенных
> подмассивов были рекурсивно "подняты" на указанный уровень depth.

```js
const obj =  {name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов'};
const arr = Object.entries(obj).flat();
console.log(arr); // ["name", "Иван", "surname", "Иванов"]
```

Comment: Как я понимаю невозможно вот так просто преобразовать без изменений это {name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов'} в это [name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов']

Comment: @iAndyPC это `[name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов']` - бессмыслица. если вам действительно нужен массив то ближайшие осмысленные вещи - это массив, как в ответе, или массив вида `[{name: 'Иван'}, {surname: 'Иванов'}]`, или массив вида `[['name', 'Иван'], ['surname', 'Иванов]]`

Comment: Просто пытаюсь выполнить учебное задание) много еще не знаю

Comment: @iAndyPC в задании точно пишут про `[name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов']`?

Comment: Написано: Результат выполнения должен быть: [ name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов' ]

Comment: @iAndyPC это строка? в js не может быть такой структуры

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, как таковой способ преобразования в `[name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов']` смысла не имеет, ведь принцип работы будет точно такой же. Но вы можете перебирать свойства объекта в цикле, так же как и массив.
Для этого используется конструкция

```
for (key in obj) {
  /* ... делать что-то с obj[key] ... */
}
```

Так же если вам нужно сделать именно массив, то можете попробовать сделать несколько иначе. Так же обходя объект способом выше, вы можете создавать новый массив помещая ключ (далее `key`) и значение (далее `value`) в ещё один массив. В итоге у вас получается `[[key, value], [key, value]]` или же `[['name', 'Иван'], ['surname', 'Иванов']]`
Тогда можно будет обращаться таким образом `arr[0][1] -> 'Иван'`

Comment: Это просто мое учебное задание, и оно похоже кривое

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj =  {name: 'Иван', surname: 'Иванов'};

let arr = new Map()
console.log(typeof(arr))
let xxx = []
console.log(typeof(xxx))
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {

arr.set(key, val)

}
xxx.push(arr)
console.log(...xxx.entries())
```

может это извращение нужно было ?:) // код тут не работает